# Как удалить поле из JSON

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

Есть допустим класс, на основе которого строится json строка

```
class LiveAddress(val region: Int,
                  val city: String,
                  val street: String,
                  val house: Int)
```

Некоторые поля для заполнения не обязательные и соответственно в json будет `"city":""` или даже `"city":null`. Не знаю как это скажется на api, возможно будет ошибка, что такого города не существует, но само поле city в json не обязательное.

Так вот возможно ли сделать такое, что если я вижу, что пользователь не ввел город, то это поле `city` вообще удалить из json строки, чтобы не посылать его на сервер?

Полей в классе может быть много, гораздо больше 4, поэтому делать кучу классов не получится. Знаю, что есть аннотация, чтобы поле класса **никогда** не попадало в json, но это **не совсем то**, ведь иногда поле должно быть в `json`.

Comment: нужно отправлять то что есть в запросе, если есть город а пользователь его не ввел, то просто отправлять null и все.

Comment: `Gson` по дефолту не сериализует поля со значением `null`. А вот с пустой строкой на сервере могут быть проблемы - лучше проверить и "обнулить" перед отправкой. Хотя если сервер нормально принимает, то можно не париться.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите убрать при сериализации в JSon определенные поля, можно попробовать аннотации, в зависимости от библиотеки:

- Jackson - вешаем  @JsonIgnore на геттер
- gson - есть вариант с использованием transient или используя комбинацию @Expose на все поля и  excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation

  ```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .registerTypeAdapter(Id.class, new IdTypeAdapter())
   .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
   .serializeNulls()
   .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation() // <--
   .setDateFormat(DateFormat.LONG)
   .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
   .setPrettyPrinting()
   .setVersion(1.0)
   .create();

  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
   .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
   .build();
  ```

Comment: тогда ведь поля пропадут при каждой сериализации. Хочется знать, возможно ли более гибко настроить, чтобы иногда при сериализации поле было в  json, а иногда нет.

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть API, в котором предусмотрен определенный формат принимаемого объекта. Не присылая какие-то поля, как бы то ни было, вы нарушаете заданный формат, что может быть воспринято со стороны Ваших коллег со стороны сервера как ошибка. В последствии также будет сложнее отследить потенциальные связанные с этим баги. Также непонятно, зачем Вам в принципе это необходимо? Экономия нескольких байт в строке вряд ли может ощутимо сказаться на производительности или памяти. Рекомендую Вам все же посылать все поля, предусмотренные API, если оно не заполнено, как уже было сказано, лучше отправлять null.